# how to add two product in opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

How to add two products . For example I added product1 . I want to split that product1 into product with media and product1 without media. Quantity are same .

In the product list it has to show in two  different entries . Below is the code for adding product. now it is taking only one ..

```
$this->data[$key] = array(
    'key'             => $key,
    'product_id'      => $product_query->row['product_id'],
    'name'            => $product_query->row['name'],
    'model'           => $product_query->row['model'],
    'shipping'        => $product_query->row['shipping'],
    'image'           => $product_query->row['image'],
    'option'          => $option_data,
    'download'        => $download_data,
    'quantity'        => $quantity,
    'minimum'         => $product_query->row['minimum'],
    'subtract'        => $product_query->row['subtract'],
    'stock'           => $stock,
    'price'           => ($price + $option_price),
    'total'           => ($price + $option_price) * $quantity,
    'reward'          => $reward * $quantity,
    'points'          => ($product_query->row['points'] ? ($product_query->row['points'] + $option_points) * $quantity : 0),
    'tax_class_id'    => $product_query->row['tax_class_id'],
    'weight'          => ($product_query->row['weight'] + $option_weight) * $quantity,
    'weight_class_id' => $product_query->row['weight_class_id'],
    'length'          => $product_query->row['length'],
    'width'           => $product_query->row['width'],
    'height'          => $product_query->row['height'],
    'length_class_id' => $product_query->row['length_class_id'],
    'recurring'       => $recurring
);
```

Comment: If you are talking about product with different option, then it will by default display products separately. But if the options are same then it will add a number of quantities

Comment: Your question is unclear, `how to add two products` to what? The cart, the database, an order ... what are you trying to do, and where is the code from that you referenced? What version of OC are you using?